# Check an Array if it contains an integer in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Is this possible and if so how would I do this correctly? Want to be able to check if it contains 1 and 2 and if so go on with the program.

```
import java.util.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int[] field = {1, 2};

        if (Arrays.asList(field).contains(1) && Arrays.asList(field).contains(2)) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use IntStream in Java 8

```
if (IntStream.of(field).anyMatch(i -> i == 1) &&
    IntStream.of(field).anyMatch(i -> i == 2)) {
    // has a 1 and a 2
```

Comment: Thank you works like a charm!

Comment: Why not use an or in the IntPredicate and have a one-liner answer? `if (IntStream.of(field).anyMatch(i -> i == 1 || I == 2)) {`

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList` works with generic types, the closest match for an `int[]` is `Object`. So you get a `List` of `int[]`. You could use `IntStream` in Java 8+ like

```
if (IntStream.of(field).anyMatch(x -> x == 1) && 
        IntStream.of(field).anyMatch(x -> x == 2)) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```